# How to sync data to Realm Object Server from NodeJS?

Tags: realm

I could register user(not admin), login, and store data in local.
But my program doesn't sync data to ROS2.

As far as I see document, maybe using `Realm.Sync.addListener` with `admin`.

I think admin user can access all object data. is wrong?

```html
const addListener = (user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Realm.Sync.addListener('realm://usme-ros.usme.local:9080', user, '.*', 'change', (back) => {
    console.log(back);
  });
});

const registerUser = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Realm.Sync.User.register(URL, username, password, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    console.log('finish register');
    resolve();
  })
});

const login = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Realm.Sync.User.login(URL, username, password, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(user);
  })
});

const registerVisit = (token) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const visitSchema = {
    name: 'Visit',
    properties: {
      id: 'int',
      oneday_id: 'string',
      arrival_date: 'string',
      departure_date: 'string',
      latitude: 'double',
      longitude: 'double',
      is_hidden: 'bool',
    }
  };

  Realm.openAsync({ schema: [visitSchema] }, (err, realm) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Visit', {
        id: 1,
        oneday_id: "ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP-QRST",
        arrival_date: "2017-11-05 11:11:11",
        departure_date: "2017-11-05 22:22:22",
        latitude: 23.1234567,
        longitude: 12.34567,
        is_hidden: false,
      });
    });
    resolve();
  });
});

login()
  .then((user) => addListener(user)
    .then(() => registerVisit())
    .catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Comment: Perhaps `Realm.Sync.addListener` means catch 'change' event...
So need admin role...

Comment: Do you have Realm Mobile Platform Professional Edition?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce no. can't develop edition?

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#data-access

Comment: @rluisr you can request a free trail at https://realm.io/trial/realm-professional-edition/